# Features Importance with list attributes from pd dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm developing a ML algorithm to get a feature importance with an ExtraTrees.
The problem that I'm trying to solving is that the variables are not scalars but lists with different dimensions, or matrixes but for now I will focus only on lists.
From the momement the only think that I was able to do is a FI with the flat lists concateneted each other.

GOAL:
What I would like to do is to get a score point for each different list instead of a score for each lists' element.

I present here a toy example of the dataset and the current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"list1": [[10,15,12,14],[20,30,10,43]], "R":[2,2] ,"C":[2,2] , "CLASS":[1,0] , "scalar1":[1,2] , "scalar2":[3,4]})
```

After PCA ( below ):

> > df['new'] = pd.Series([a.reshape((c, r)) for (a, c, r) in zip(df.A, df.C, df.R)])
> >
> > df['pca'] = pd.Series([ pca_volatilities(matrix) for matrix in df.new ])

Becomes:

```
    list1 # C # C1 #    C2 #    CLASS # R # new #   pca #   flat_pca    
0   [10, 15, 12, 14]    2   1   3   1   2   [[10, 15], [12, 14]]    [[-1.11803398875], [1.11803398875]]     [-1.11803398875, 1.11803398875] 
1   [20, 30, 10, 43]    2   2   4   0   2   [[20, 30], [10, 43]]    [[-8.20060973343], [8.20060973343]]     [-8.20060973343, 8.20060973343]
```

Here I present the fit:

```
X = np.concatenate([np.stack(df.flat_pca,axis=0), [df.C1, df.C2]], axis=0).transpose()
Y = np.array(df.CLASS)

model = ExtraTreesRegressor()
model.fit(X,Y)
model.feature_importances_
```

This returns:
    array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.2,  0.3]).

What I need is a score for list1 , C1,C2 and flat_pca. I don't know how to do this.

Hoping that someone is able to help me, thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: I've reasoned a lot on this problem. Since the algorithm that will use the features, we'll treat them as scalars there is no reason to keep this granularity. 
However, there might be other reason to this requirement such as: discover which original features are more important to predict the target. So the problem is still open. ( at least to me )